# Easy access helper for JSON.parse in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, design-patterns, code-structure

To convert any object into a JSON, we have `foo.to_json` helper in ruby which returns a string. Similarly, to convert it back to its original datatype, we have to use `JSON.parse(json_string)`, which does not look as good as `foo.to_json` (IMHO).

So I tried to implement a helper function for that in ruby using the following code:

```
class String
  def parse_json
    JSON.parse(self)
  end
end
```

But none of the languages I know of has such a helper method in the String class. This makes me wonder, is it a bad pattern to write code like this? The String instance should not be responsible for decoding itself into some other type of object that is present in the JSON?

Comment: Related reading: [active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb)

Comment: If it's a Gem meant to be used by others, then I don't suggest messing with core, unless it's an explicit decision by the programmer, like they have to do `require 'cool_gem/core_ext'`, but `require 'cool_gem'` should **not** do it by default. This is typically what Gems do. If it's an app, then it's fine, and even done a lot by Rubyists. Rails does it a lot, for example. JSON/YAML do it by adding `to_json/to_yaml` to `Object` already. It's fine, but just be careful and use a unique name (like you have already done).

Comment: @esotericpig to_json/to_yaml are more excusable though since Psych and JSON are part of the Ruby stdlib.

Comment: @max A lot of Gems do what I said, which don't mess with stdlib by default, but have an option, like `require 'rainbow/refinement'` I definitely don't think it should be by default. Now, for an App (that no one will ever add as a dependency and require), I think it's even more okay to do it. Before Rails was popular, they were messing with stdlib, and it probably became more popular from it. It just depends on what you're making. For a Gem, never do it by default, I agree (unless your Gem is explicitly a collection of core extensions).

Comment: Thank you. It's not for a gem. It's for an app :)